# FreeRadius - Authenticate any User & Password

Tags: authentication, radius

I am trying to help a facility who's radius server crashed - no recoverable data.

The clients are all installed (buried) in vehicles and are not readily accessible (need to tear stuff apart).

Access Point is an Orinoco AP-700, FreeRadius running on Centos validating to mysql.

Is there any way to adjust the settings so that ANY user/pass combo will be authenticated and allowed in?  I could then ssh to the remote unit and re-configure the user/password settings on each unit.

I tried editing the /etc/init.d/users as listed below -

> DEFAULT Auth-Type := Accept
>
> session-timeout = 14400,
>
> Termination-Action = RADIUS-Request

Restarted Radius - and.... nope.  Still is not authenticating "any-user" or "any-password".

Additional thoughts/feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a backup of the `users` file usually `/etc/raddb/users`, remove all content and enter only the below text for accepting all requests by default.

```
DEFAULT Auth-Type := Accept
session-timeout = 14400,
Termination-Action = RADIUS-Request
```

And of course, restart Radius service. I hope that's what you wanted to do.

Comment: Wish they knew 5 years ago to take a copy of the users file - but they did not.  No hard copy either.

Comment: @Justin60047: Then just do the changes like I said above. Doesn't matter anyways, in your case.

Comment: No need to delete complete users file. Just add those lines above all others...